# Sell stock without a full broker account

Tags: stocks, broker, selling

I have a few stocks from a public company. I got them after a startup I worked in got acquired by this public company. So now I have an account on AST Financials, and my stocks are in their books (I don't have any certificate currently).

Sadly, the company doesn't offer any way to sell the stocks directly from AST Financials, so I suppose I have to open an account to a broker, transfer my stock (with ACAT transfer I suppose), sell my stocks and then close my account and transfer the money to my bank account.

So I have 2 questions :

- Is there any simpler way to do that? Are there any broker services that take your stocks, sell them at the market value, and wire the money to your bank account?
- If not, what broker would you recommend to do this operation? I don't want to do any trading, I would prefer to avoid having to wire any money to the broker (just my stocks), and I would love to minimize fees and the complexity of the process :D.

Please also note that I don't have American citizenship, not sure if that has any kind of influence on my question.

Thanks!

Ps: The approximate value of the stocks is around $40k

Comment: What you describe sounds correct. US brokerages will usually pay any transfer fees if pulling from another brokerage or transfer agent. You should clearly state what is your US status (just in case), and where the bank account is located (US or non-US). You are still responsible for taxes.

Comment: I just want to echo what Morrison is saying, I've never "net-paid" a transfer fee; any fee has been paid back to me either as a reimbursement or a "new account" bonus that was larger than the fee at the new broker.

Answer (score 1):

[Fidelity](https://www.fidelity.com/customer-service/transfer-assets) says no fees to transfer in; you would have to contact AST for their fees to transfer out, if any.